# Inner join, count and group by to get ratios

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, inner-join

I'm hoping this will be a simple question for somebody who knows what they're doing with mysql.

I have two tables at the moment; 'tasks' and 'completion'.

Tasks:

```
taskID  |  task_name  |  desciption  |  deadline
1       |  task 1     |  do this     | 2012-08-11
2       |  task 2     |  do that     | 2012-10-11
3       |  task 3     |  do the other| 2012-12-31
```

Completion:

```
taskID  |  userID  |  status
1       |  24      |  complete
1       |  72      |  complete
1       |  15      |  late
2       |  41      |  complete
2       |  86      |  incomplete
3       |  4       |  incomplete
3       |  19      |  incomplete
```

I'm trying to retrieve the ratio of users who have completed (ontime OR late) each task which has passed its deadline date all in one query (like below):

```
taskID  |  task_name  |  description  |  deadline  |  completion_ratio
1       |  task 1     |  do this      | 2012-08-11 |  0.66666
2       |  task 2     |  do that      | 2012-10-11 |  0.5
```

Task 3 does not show because the deadline has not passed.

The following code gives me a nice simple join on the two tables and selects only those tasks which have passed their deadline date but I would like to know how to get the result shown above.

```
SELECT task.taskID,task.task_name,task.description,task.deadline,completion.status
  FROM task 
  INNER JOIN completion ON task.taskID=completion.taskID 
  WHERE task.deadline>=CURDATE()
```

Result from query:

```
taskID  |  task_name  |  description  |  deadline  |  status
1       |  task 1     |  do this      | 2012-08-11 | complete
1       |  task 1     |  do this      | 2012-08-11 | complete
1       |  task 1     |  do this      | 2012-08-11 | late
2       |  task 2     |  do that      | 2012-10-11 | complete
2       |  task 2     |  do that      | 2012-10-11 | incomplete
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here also, as per table data provided in question :

```
SELECT T.task_id,
  T.task_name,
  T.description,
  T.deadline,
  SUM( if(C.status = 'complete', 1, 0)) * 1.0 /count(C.status)
FROM tasks AS T
INNER JOIN completions AS C ON T.task_id = C.task_id 
GROUP BY T.task_id
HAVING T.deadline >= CURDATE()
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b1da/1)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  t.taskID,
  t.task_name,
  t.desciption, 
  t.deadline,
  SUM(CASE WHEN c.status = 'complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0 / 
  COUNT(c.status) AS completion_ratio
FROM tasks t
INNER JOIN completion c ON t.taskID = c.taskID 
WHERE t.deadline >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY   t.taskID,
  t.task_name,
  t.desciption, 
  t.deadline;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/890ff/2)<sup>**Note that:** I modified the dates in the fiddle demo for demonstration.</sup>

This will give you:

```
| TASKID | TASK_NAME | DESCIPTION |   DEADLINE | COMPLETION_RATIO |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1 |    task 1 |    do this | 2012-12-30 |          0.66667 |
|      2 |    task 2 |    do that | 2012-12-31 |              0.5 |
```

Comment: @MahmoudGamal but you haven't took `Task deadline` values as mentioned in question

Comment: @rkp I modified the deadline values, becuase the `CURDATE()` returns only the task 3, so I modified it for better demonstration as I mentioned in my answer. If this was a problem I can use the same data in the question. After all it is just sample data.